# Prediction file format in vowpal wabbit with bootstrapping

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I'm using VW 7.4 to do some binary classification:

```
cat train | vw -k --binary --cache_file cache -f model --compressed --passes 10 --loss_function hinge
```

At test time, I can access the scores using:

```
cat test | vw -t -i model -p pred
```

What I don't get is that, if I add `--bootstrap 4` to training, then the resulting `pred` file contains 3 columns. I don't know which of them corresponds to the scores of the prediction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `--bootstrap <N>` vowpal-wabbit adds a confidence [min max] interval resulting from the multiple bootstrapping samples, to each prediction line:

```
prediction tag min max
```

The first two fields remain as they were without `--bootstrap`:

```
prediction tag
```

(`tag` is optional; it is echoed from the respective example in the data-set, and its use is recommended)

You can find more details in [Zhen Qin's presentation slides](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Zhen.pdf) on the new features he contributed (including but not limited to `--bootstrap`)

Unrelated, but has to be mentioned:

You [don't have to feed vowpal-wabbit from `stdin` using `cat file |`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat)).  You can save a process by passing the data-set file directly to `vw`:

```
vw ... filename
```